# Mybatis property mapper error for List of objects in pojo class : spring Boot/mybatis

Tags: database, spring-boot, ibatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

**Please help** : Issue description in below image URL,  Issue description in below image URL,  even setting property to cost/margin/retail  or currentday also not working in mapper interface, Let me know, if i need to follow anything else?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPI7p.png
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, they are not usable to provide support and reproduce the problem. Put all the code in the question as a [mre] and clearly describe the problem. The screenshot should be unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map a nested object in Mybatis; you have to write multiple queries to achieve this or switch to Hibernate.